# Не получается загрузить файл на сервер

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, .net-core

Всем доброго времени суток, есть проект клиент-сервер, клиент на ангуляре, сервер на коре. На сервере код загрузки файла:

```
[HttpPost("[action]/{formData}"), Route("addfile")]
        public async Task AddFile(IFormFile formData)
        {

                // путь к папке Files
                string path = "/Files/" + formData.FileName;
                // сохраняем файл в папку Files в каталоге wwwroot
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath + path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await formData.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
                FileModel file = new FileModel { Name = formData.FileName, Path = path };
                db.Files.Add(file);
                db.SaveChanges();

        }
```

на клиенте:
Компонент:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'add-file',
  templateUrl: './add-files.component.html',

})

export class AddFilesComponent implements OnInit {

  fileData: File = null;
  previewUrl: any = null;
  fileUploadProgress: string = null;
  uploadedFilePath: string = null;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  fileProgress(fileInput: any) {
    this.fileData = <File>fileInput.target.files[0];
    this.preview();
  }

  preview() {
    // Show preview 
    var mimeType = this.fileData.type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileData);
    reader.onload = (_event) => {
      this.previewUrl = reader.result;
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('files', this.fileData);

    this.fileUploadProgress = '0%';

    this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/file/addfile', formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events'
    })
      .subscribe(events => {
        if (events.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
          this.fileUploadProgress = Math.round(events.loaded / events.total * 100) + '%';
          console.log(this.fileUploadProgress);
        } else if (events.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          this.fileUploadProgress = '';
          console.log(events.body);
          alert('SUCCESS !!');
        }

      }) 
  }
}
```

ХТМЛ:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <h3>Choose File</h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="image" (change)="fileProgress($event)" />
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fileUploadProgress">
        Upload progress: {{ fileUploadProgress }}
      </div>
      <div class="image-preview mb-3" *ngIf="previewUrl">
        <img [src]="previewUrl" height="300" />
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3" *ngIf="uploadedFilePath">
        {{uploadedFilePath}}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Примечание: Если реализовывать все только в коре, то все работает, файл загружается, значит с кодом все в порядке. Проблема в том, что файл не приходит с сервера, прошел точкой останова на клиенте, файл отправляется, ставлю точку останова на сервере, запускаю все по новой, реакция есть, то есть клиент запускает метод на сервере, однако я вижу, что `IFormFile formData`
равен null, а значит что и сохранять нечего.. чувствую что в мелочи ошибся, ткните где плс...

Comment: Зачем вот тут `"[action]/{formData}"` formdata?

Comment: @tym32167 убрал уже, оставил `[HttpPost, Route("addfile")]`, но все осталось как прежде...

Comment: Обычно он равен null когда фреймворк asp не может привести то что вы посылаете к тому типу который ожидается. Попробуйте в параметре метода контроллера написать так AddFile([FromBody]object formData), это позволит вам понять какие поля приходят с фронтенда и на основе этого уже перепишите свой интерфейс IFormFile

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov В общем сделал вот так 
`[HttpPost("[action]"), Route("addfile")]`
`public async Task AddFile([FromForm]IFormFile files)`

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так:

```
[HttpPost("[action]"), Route("addfile")]
public async Task AddFile([FromForm]IFormFile files)
```

И все заработало, всем спасибо!